# Proving existence of at least one root

Tags: analysis, continuity

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, is continuous and $a>0$.
How can I prove that there is at least one root of this equation:

$f(x)=f(\sqrt{|x^2-a|})$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto f(\sqrt{|x^2-a|})-f(x)$ is continuous, maps $0\mapsto f(\sqrt a)-f(0)$ and $\sqrt a\mapsto f(0)-f(\sqrt a)$. Now use the IVT.

Comment: In fact, we don't even need to require that $f$ be continuous: the function $x \mapsto x - \sqrt{|x^2-a|}$ must have a root $y \in (0, \sqrt{a})$ by the intermediate value theorem, and clearly $f(y) = f(\sqrt{|y^2-a|})$

Comment: @Strants Why not write that as a separate answer?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I figured it was morally very similar to Hagan von Eitzen's answer (in that it has the form: set up an auxiliary function, apply IVT to said function), so I didn't quite feel it warranted a separate answer.